# how to code "hello" == obj without overload the operator==?

Tags: c++, string, templates, operator-overloading

I create a class string witch is template for using both `char*` and `wchar_t`.
I want to compile `obj == " word"` and the opposite without overload the `operator==` for each case.

I already tried to use operator conversion but it doesnt work.

```
template<typename T>
class String
{
    friend bool operator==<T>(const String<T>& a, const String<T>& b);

public:
    typedef T Type_value;
    String(const Type_value* str = "");
    String(const String& str);
    String& operator=(const String& original);
    operator T* ();
    operator std::string ();

    ~String();

private:
    size_t m_size; 
    Buffer<Type_value> m_buff;
};

template <typename T>
bool operator== (const String<T>& a, const String<T>& b )
{
    return UtilString<T>::Compare(a.m_buff, b.m_buff) == 0;
}


template<typename T>
String<T>::operator T* ()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_buff.Begin());
}

template<typename T>
String<T>::operator std::string ()
{
    return string(m_buff.Begin());
}
```

I want that `"hello" == String<char>("hello")` works.

Comment: `"word" == "word"` has unspecified result, better/safer to add `operator ==` than conversion operator.

Comment: *"without overload the operator== for each case"* - why?

Comment: @WhozCraig: As OP has `bool operator== (const String<T>& a, const String<T>& b )`, I think he want to avoid to implement all variants between `String<T>`/`const char*/const wchar_t*` and reuse the one OP wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with:

```
template <typename T>
bool operator== (const String<T>& a, const String<T>& b )
```

is the deduction of `T`, and for `"hello" == String<char>("hello")`, `"hello"` doesn't match `const String<T>&`, so that overload is discarded.

What you can do is to make it non template:

```
template <typename T>
class String
{
    // non template function.
    friend bool operator==(const String& lhs, const String& rhs)
    {
        return UtilString<T>::Compare(a.m_buff, b.m_buff) == 0;
    }
    // ...    

};
```

So `"hello" == String<char>("hello")` would consider overload (thanks to rhs)

```
operator==(const String<char>& lhs, const String<char>& rhs)
```

and would construct `String<char>` from `"hello"` as constructor is viable.